# QtDesigner shipped with QGIS 3 doesn't show svg files preview in resources

Tags: qgis-3, svg, qt-designer

In the QtDesigner shipped with QGIS 3 svg's and jpg's are not shown in the Resources window nor as icons on widgets:

QtDesigner from QGIS 3.2:

svg's example

[image]

jpg's example

[image]

QtDesigner from QGIS 2.18

svg's example

[image]

jpg's example

[image]

In a QGIS 3 plugin that uses the .ui file the icons on any widget display correctly, so the result is ok, but working with the QtDesigner that comes with QGIS 3 is hardly possible in my case.

Is there a way to make it show my svg's and jpg's as usual, and if not, is it critical or unsafe to use QGIS 2's QtDesigner for QGIS 3 plugin guis?

Comment: What about png files? They seem to load fine in my 3.2 version when converted from jpeg.

Comment: png no problem, but my svg's... :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, I would like to mention that problems sometimes solve themselves, such in this case.

For QtDesigner shipped with the recent QGIS 3.18.2 all graphic formats display well:

jpg:

[image]

svg:

[image]